# Are multi-sigs multiple keys signing on a single shared signature, or one signature per key?

Tags: multisignature

And if it is a single shared signature, how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Multisig is multiple keys with one signature per key.

[Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) is how a single key can be split in multiple parts, and those parts combined to recover the key (which can be used to create a signature):

> a form of secret sharing, where a secret is divided into parts, giving each participant its own unique part, where some of the parts or all of them are needed in order to reconstruct the secret.
>
> Counting on all participants to combine the secret might be impractical, and therefore sometimes the threshold scheme is used where any `k` of the parts are sufficient to reconstruct the original secret.

A Github or web search on "shamir secret sharing" will help you find implementations.